# difference between running a query to yahoo finance calendar earning in browser and running the same query in python?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I want to get all the historical earnings dates for GE from yahoo finance. If I run the query in the firefox browser it works but in code it does not. It returns not just GE but all earnings for all companies for day. I don't understand what is going on??

if I run this in the browser

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?symbol=GE
```

I get

```
Symbol
    Company Earnings Date
EPS Estimate    Reported EPS    Surprise(%)

GE
    General Electric Company    Oct 24, 2023, 2 AMEDT   0.56    0.82    +46.43
GE
    General Electric Company    Jul 25, 2023, 2 AMEDT   0.46    0.68    +46.87
GE
    General Electric Company    Apr 25, 2023, 2 AMEDT   0.14    0.27    +97.53
GE
    General Electric Company    Jan 24, 2023, 1 AMEST   1.13    1.24    +9.26
```

which is what I want

BUT if I run it in my code

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?symbol=GE"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

print(df)
```

I get

```
   Symbol                                            Company  \
0    ATNF                             180 Life Sciences Corp   
1    TURN                            180 Degree Capital Corp   
2    BCOW                      1895 Bancorp of Wisconsin Inc   
3    DIBS                                    1stdibs.Com Inc   
4    DIBS                                    1stdibs.Com Inc   
..    ...                                                ...   
95  IDGBF                         Indigo Books and Music Inc   
96  IDGBF                         Indigo Books and Music Inc   
97  CDPYF  Canadian Apartment Properties Real Estate Inve...   
98   PAHC                          Phibro Animal Health Corp   
99   CPSI                  Computer Programs and Systems Inc
```

which is NOT what I want.

Comment: The web site uses JavaScript to add the other columns dynamically. `read_html()` doesn't execute JS.

Comment: @Barmar - How about `requests.get`?

Comment: No. You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver. See the linked question.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much for the information I have NO clue when it comes to JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar just tried Selenium and it's not for me. Thanks so much for the suggestion.

Comment: you don't need to know JavaScript to use Selenium. It emulates a web browser and that will execute the JS.

Comment: thanks for all your help @Barmar I did try and kept hitting error after errors. I'll give selenium a miss but thanks again.

Comment: did you try to use module `yfinance`?  This seems gives expected values: `import yfinance as yf` `stock = yf.Ticker("GE")` `ES = stock.get_earnings_dates()` `print(ES.head(10))`

Comment: hi @furas I did, that was the first thing I tried but I need to get the historic dates and that code ( I tried exactly that code) only goes back to 2022-01-25.  Thank you so much for taking the time but I need the dates back to 2017.

Comment: Use parameter `limit=100` in `.get_earnings_dates(limit=100)` and you get even year `2000`.

Comment: @furas I don't care what the others say ;-) you are a genius!!!! worked perfectly except for the future warning but...  thanks so much, you made my night!!!